# Custom component won't return value

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, custom-component

OK, this is the situation. In my `beforeSave` function I want to manipulate some `$this->request->data` entries.

This is my component:

```
<?php
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');
class GetStationComponent extends Component {
    public function getStationId ($station) { 
        $stationInstance = ClassRegistry::init('Station');

        $conditions = array('OR' => array(
            array('Station.code LIKE' => $station),
            array('Station.naam LIKE' => $station),
            array('Station.naam_overig LIKE' => $station)
            ));

        $result = $stationInstance->find('list', array('conditions'=>$conditions));

        $value = array_values($result);
        $value = $value[0];

        return $value;
    }
}
?>
```

And this is my beforeSave function in  my Controller:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (!empty($this->request->data['Experience']['vertrekstation']) && !empty($this->request->data['Experience']['aankomststation'])) {
            $this->request->data['Experience']['vertrekstation'] = $this->GetStation->getStationId($this->request->data['Experience']['vertrekstation']);
            $this->request->data['Experience']['aankomststation'] = $this->GetStation->getStationId($this->request->data['Experience']['aankomststation']);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

It should return an ID of the stations name. But in the Database the name itself is stored (which is filled in by the user) instead of the ID. What do I need to change in my Component (I guess...) to return the right values?

(P.S. The query itself in the component returns an ID, because at first I'd put the 'beforeSave' directly into my function which saves the data, but then my validation error said that it wasn't a right value. Which is correct...)

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `array_keys()` in stead of `array_values()`? Or simply `key($result)` to get the first key in the results [PHP key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php). Finally, you need to check if `$result` actually contains a result, maybe `find('first')` is more suitable here

Comment: Well, I don't know why, but if I use `find('first')` it returns an array `array(
 'Station' => array(
  'id' => '132'
 )
)`. Then I have to modify it again. What I'm actualy looking for is just to pull the id from my list, a regular MySQL query would look like this:
`'SELECT Experience.id FROM Experiences WHERE Experience.code LIKE {$value} OR Experience.naam LIKE {$value} OR  Experience.naam_overig LIKE {$value}'` But for some reason, I can't manage to get this via Cake's way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement the other answers; to get just the value of a single field, use [`Model::field()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-field)

```
return $stationInstance->field('id', $conditions);
```

It is best to add a sort order to this statement to make sure that the results will always be returned in the same order:

```
return $stationInstance->field('id', $conditions, 'code ASC');
```

Since you only perform a single query on the Model, and don't do anything afterwards, you don't even need the intermediate `$stationInstance` variable. Your code can be further simplified to:

```
return ClassRegistry::init('Station')->field('id', $conditions, 'code ASC');
```

### Some observations

- Because of the 'fuzzy' matching on the name of the station, the first result may not always be the station *intended* by the user it's best to offer an 'autocomplete' functionality in your front-end and have the user pick the *correct* station (e.g. To prevent picking `Den Haag` when the user *meant* `Den Haag HS`)
- If the station does *not* fully matches a station, you should present a warning that the station wasn't found
- You didn't surround your search-terms with `%` for the `LIKE` queries. If you intend to search for 'name *"contains"*, you should use `'%' . $station . '%'`. For *"starts with"* use `$station . '%'`
- As @mark suggested; `beforeSave()` is a callback of the *Model* and should be located there.
  Also; `beforeSave()` is triggered after validation has taken place, so it will probably be too late. `beforeValidate()` is the best callback for this
- If the `Experience` model is already attached to the `Station` model, you don't need to use a component, because you can directly access the `Station` model. It's best to put the search-method inside the `Station` model;

### Moving it all to the right(*) location

*) Other options are always possible, this is just *a possible* approach

Add the 'search' method to the Station-model;

app/Model/Station.php

```
public function getStationIdByName($name)
{
    $name = trim($name);

    if (empty($name)) {
        return null;
    }

    $name = '%' . $name . '%';

    $conditions = array(
        'OR' => array(
            array($this->alias . '.code LIKE' => $name),
            array($this->alias . '.naam LIKE' => $name),
            array($this->alias . '.naam_overig LIKE' => $name),
        )
    );

    return $this->field('id', $conditions, 'code ASC');
}
```

..and use it in the Experience Model

app/Model/Experience.php

```
public function beforeValidate(array $options = array())
{
    if (
        !empty($this->data[$this->alias]['vertrekstation'])
        && !empty($this->data[$this->alias]['aankomststation'])
    ) {
        // Directly access the Station-model from within the Experience Model
        $this->data[$this->alias]['vertrekstation'] 
            = $this->Station->getStationIdByName($this->data[$this->alias]['vertrekstation']);
        $this->data[$this->alias]['aankomststation']
            = $this->Station->getStationIdByName($this->data[$this->alias]['aankomststation']);
    }

    // Call parent-callback after setting the values
    return parent::beforeValidate($options);
}
```

### [UPDATE] Using the Conventions, prevent unwanted behavior

After writing the previous example, I noticed there are some flaws in your current setup;

1. If *vertrekstation* and *aankomststation* should hold the 'foreign key' of the station (the station-**id**) they are not named according to the [CakePHP Model and Database Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)
2. Because of `1)` By putting this code inside the `beforeValidate()`, it will also be triggered when ***updating*** an existing record. Because you're using the *aankomststation* and *vertrekstation* field both to hold the *name* of the station (inside the Form) and the *id* (inside the database), the Model will attempt to look-up the station-id via the *id* when updating. NOTE that **inside the *form*** you'll still be using *vertrekstation* and *aankomstation* as field-name. These field names are *not* present in your database, and therefore will not be able to directly update data inside your database, that's where the `beforeValidate()` callback is used for
3. Because the `Experience` model needs *two* relations to the `Station` model (once as `departure station` (*'vertrekstation'*), once for `arrival station` (*'aankomststation'*)), you will need an *alias* for the Station-model. See: [Multiple relations to the same model](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-relations-to-the-same-model)

app/Model/Experience.php

```
class Experience extends AppModel {
    /**
     * Station will be associated to the 'Experience' Model TWICE
     * For clarity, using an 'alias' for both associations
     *
     * The associated Models will be accessible via;
     * $this->DepartureStation
     * $this->ArrivalStation
     *
     * To stick to the CakePHP conventions, name the foreign keys
     * accordingly
     */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'DepartureStation' => array(
            'className'  => 'Station',
            'foreignKey' => 'departure_station_id',
        ),
        'ArrivalStation' => array(
            'className'  => 'Station',
            'foreignKey' => 'arrival_station_id',
        )
    );

    public function beforeValidate(array $options = array())
    {
        // vertrekstation and aankomststation hold the 'names' of the
        // stations and will only be present if the form has been submitted
        if (
            !empty($this->data[$this->alias]['vertrekstation'])
            && !empty($this->data[$this->alias]['aankomststation'])
        ) {
            // Directly access the Station-model from within the Experience Model
            // using the *aliases*
            $this->data[$this->alias]['departure_station_id'] 
                = $this->DepartureStation->getStationIdByName($this->data[$this->alias]['vertrekstation']);
            $this->data[$this->alias]['arrival_station_id']
                = $this->ArrivalStation->getStationIdByName($this->data[$this->alias]['aankomststation']);

            // Invalidate the vertrekstation and aankomststation fields if lookup failed
            if (empty($this->data[$this->alias]['departure_station_id'])) {
                // Unable to find a station. Mark the Form-field invalid
                $this->invalidate('vertrekstation', __('A station with this name was not found'));
            }
            if (empty($this->data[$this->alias]['arrival_station_id'])) {
                // Unable to find a station. Mark the Form-field invalid
                $this->invalidate('aankomststation', __('A station with this name was not found'));
            }

        }

        // Call parent-callback after setting the values
        return parent::beforeValidate($options);
    }

}
```

Comment: OK, there is a lot of useful information in this answer. Thank you VERY much for that. I can't respond to all your information, so I'll keep it short. In the validation rules the stationname is checked against de records in the database. That's why I need to change the input name AFTER validation. Nevertheless, a autocomplete would work. I will implement this, but for now, my knowledge about JSON is too low. I've read multiple questions about this on stack, so it'll come. Thanks again for your great answer!

Comment: With my last example, you should be able to achieve that; If the system was unable to find a station, based on the name, the `departing_station_id` and/or `arrival_station_id` fields will be empty. In order to show the Form-fields as invalid, you can manually invalidate them. I updated the example

Comment: OK, so... If I'm not mistaken, you suggest that I should rename (according to the CakePHP conventions) my fieldnames of 'vertrekstation' and 'aankomststation' in my `Experiences` table to respectively '`arrival_station_id`' and '`departure_station_id`'. To prevent problems when updating the record.

Comment: And another thing (I'm sorry, I thought I did understand the CakePHP system by now...), do I need to specify a `hasMany` relation in my `Station` model, to the `Experience` model? Or is that only neccesary when it is a 'two-way' connection ('cause the `Station` model has pretty low (say: none) influence to the `Experience` model...)

Comment: Yup, when using a foreign-key, you should name the foreign key: `[lowercase_name_of_other_model][underscore][fieldname_in_other_model]`. The hasMany in the 'Station' model *is* possible, but not required if you never want to show all "Experiences" for a station. You may need to define *two* hasMany relations as well (Experiences are connected to a station, either via `departure_station_id` or `arrival_station_id`), or use a custom condition for the hasMany

Answer (score 0):

The find('list') option of Cake returns an array like

```
array( 1 => 'name1',
       3 => 'name2',
       //etc...
)
```

where the index is the id and the value is the *display field* you set on the model.
So, when you do `$value = array_values($result);`, you're extracting the values of the array (meaning, the display fields). I'm assuming you're not using the id as the displayField, so that's why it's returning the names and not the id.

I'm not sure why you're using find('list') instead of find('first') or other alternative, but if you don't want to modify that for whatever reason, the fix that should return the first id obtained by the search is

```
reset($result);  //possibly not needed, but just in case
$value = key($result );
```

Comment: Yeah, but I do need the value, because Cake serves me an Array. See my reaction at @theJeztah 's comment.

Answer (score 0):

First you must understand how Cake works
There is no `$this->request` in your models. Its part of the controller.
In your model your passed data will be in `$this->data` directly.

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    parent::beforeSave($options); // you also forgot the parent call

    if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['vertrekstation']) && ...)) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['vertrekstation'] = ...;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Your find call also looks pretty screwed up. I dont know what you want to do.
But I strongly advice you to use debug() etc to find out what is returned and correct your code accordingly.
You probably need find(first) if you are only interesting in a single value.

Comment: OK, my mistake... In my staring I didn't see that it's actually a Callback for a model. I was allready wondering why they didn't put `->request` in there. I'll try to mess around with your solution. Need to say that the Book doesn't mention anything about the parent call... See [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave)